# Workaround to use cache-headers plugin without logging dependency

Tags: grails

I'd like to use logback plugin along with cache-headers plugin. The problem is that cache-headers depends on the logging plugin, whereas logback need it to be removed.

Is there a way to get rid of a plugin's plugin dependency in grails (Aether) ?

That dependency is removed in cache-headers version 1.1.6, but it hasn't been released :
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/cache-headers-1-1-6-release-td4651033.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I released version 1.1.6 with this fix and some other cleanup.

Comment: The best answer by far.

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a release planned soon the best solution is to build the plugin yourself and push it to some internal or personal maven repo. You can use the grails release plugin to deploy the code to a maven repo instead of grails central.